# Bokeh simple bar chart

Tags: bokeh

I'm new to the method. I created the following input, but it gives me an empty output. What did I miss? Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.charts import Bar
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
mortality_age = pd.read_csv("mortality_by_age.csv")
x=mortality_age["Age Range"]
y=mortality_age["Deaths per 100,000 Live Births:"]
plot = figure(title="Example of a vertical bar chart")
plot.vbar(x, top=y, width=0.5,color="#CAB2D6")
output_file("vertical_bar.html", mode="inline")
show(plot)
```

Answer (score 0):

what version of Bokeh are you using?

Using 12.10, I have managed to get a plot to show using the code below, using the example contained in the [documentation](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/plotting/file/bar_chart.py).

```
# import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
# from bokeh.charts import Bar  # I had issues with this line working
# mortality_age = pd.read_csv("mortality_by_age.csv")
# x=mortality_age["Age Range"]
# y=mortality_age["Deaths per 100,000 Live Births:"]
x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y=[6, 7, 6, 4, 5]
plot = figure(title="Example of a vertical bar chart")
plot.vbar(x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], top=y, width=0.5, color="#CAB2D6")
output_file("vertical_bar.html", mode="inline")
show(plot)
```

My recommendations would be to check the version of bokeh you are using, and then check the data contained in your csv file, it might be possible there is nothing in there.